# Looking for a shoujo/romance one-shot manga

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, manga

I am looking for a short manga or a one-shot (not really sure) about the main guy who bumps into a girl on his way to school and the girl drops her hair pin which she got from her crush (childhood friend, I think). The main guy is cold at first but likes the girl later and he plays a football game against the girl's crush where he gets injured. The age of the MCs are around 16-17 (high school). It's a shoujo\romance manga.

I also remember the MC being popular but odd, he takes the female MC on a date by force even though she has a boyfriend at that time and they meet the boyfriend by chance. Also I remember there was a scene with the female MC and the guy she likes at the beginning at the bus stop, that where they become a couple and if I am not mistaken he asks about the hair pin she lost because of the male MC (she finds it later ).

Also if I am not mistaken at the end she still has that pin and the male MC sees that she still has it and was upset but she said that she is keeping it because he found it for her and also that's how they met and not because of the guy who gave it to her.

Comment: [Previous comments thread on Anime.SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/51182/2516) and [its chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91103/id-request-001) for (additional) context.

Answer (score 4):

Just here to say I finally found what I am looking for. It's a short manga called *Getsuyoubi Kara Kataomoi*. 
Well this manga is about the male MC having everything in life and desiring nothing until he meets the female MC and falls in love with her and we will see him trying his best to get her to look his way even though he knows she already loves someone else .

Comment: That's great! You should be able to mark your answer as accepted in a few days